# sp_procoption is not executing the join query on MSDB under stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, optimization

I am using sp_procoption to extract failed job details and backup information
But it is not generating any result when executed through sp_procoption but same is working fine when I execute the procedure manually.

is it happening because of joins I used in code, even I used waitfor delay before insert to give some seconds for sql server to ready,but no luck. I am really eager to know the reason behind it to resolve this issue.

```html
Use master
go
CREATE PROCEDURE  [dbo].[job details] 
@JobName NVARCHAR (1000)
AS
IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#JobResults','U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #JobResults
CREATE TABLE #JobResults ( Job_ID   UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL, 
                                   Last_Run_Date         INT NOT NULL, 
                                   Last_Run_Time         INT NOT NULL, 
                                   Next_Run_date         INT NOT NULL, 
                                   Next_Run_Time         INT NOT NULL, 
                                   Next_Run_Schedule_ID  INT NOT NULL, 
                                   Requested_to_Run      INT NOT NULL,
                                   Request_Source        INT NOT NULL, 
                                   Request_Source_id     SYSNAME 
                                   COLLATE Database_Default      NULL, 
                                   Running               INT NOT NULL,
                                   Current_Step          INT NOT NULL, 
                                   Current_Retry_Attempt INT NOT NULL, 
                                   Job_State             INT NOT NULL ) 
INSERT  #JobResults 
        EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_sqlagent_enum_jobs 1, '';

        SELECT  job.name                                                AS [Job_Name], 
              ( SELECT  MAX(CAST( STUFF(STUFF(CAST(jh.run_date AS VARCHAR),7,0,'-'),5,0,'-') + ' ' + 
                        STUFF(STUFF(REPLACE(STR(jh.run_time,6,0),' ','0'),5,0,':'),3,0,':') AS DATETIME))
                FROM    msdb.dbo.sysjobs AS j 
                    INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory AS jh 
                       ON jh.job_id = j.job_id AND jh.step_id = 0 
                WHERE j.[name] LIKE '%' + @JobName + '%' 
                GROUP BY j.[name] )                                     AS [Last_Completed_DateTime], 
              ( SELECT  TOP 1 start_execution_date 
                FROM    msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity
                WHERE   job_id = r.job_id
                ORDER BY start_execution_date DESC )                    AS [Job_Start_DateTime],
            CASE 
                WHEN r.running = 0 THEN
                    CASE 
                        WHEN jobInfo.lASt_run_outcome = 0 THEN 'Failed'
                        WHEN jobInfo.lASt_run_outcome = 1 THEN 'Success'
                        WHEN jobInfo.lASt_run_outcome = 3 THEN 'Canceled'
                        ELSE 'Unknown'
                    END
                        WHEN r.job_state = 0 THEN 'Success'
                        WHEN r.job_state = 4 THEN 'Success'
                        WHEN r.job_state = 5 THEN 'Success'
                        WHEN r.job_state = 1 THEN 'In Progress'
                        WHEN r.job_state = 2 THEN 'In Progress'
                        WHEN r.job_state = 3 THEN 'In Progress'
                        WHEN r.job_state = 7 THEN 'In Progress'
                     ELSE 'Unknown' END                                 AS [Run_Status_Description]
        FROM    #JobResults AS r 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobservers AS jobInfo 
               ON r.job_id = jobInfo.job_id 
            INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs AS job 
               ON r.job_id = job.job_id 
        WHERE   job.[enabled] = 1
                AND job.name LIKE '%' + @JobName + '%'
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Startup procedures cannot contain `INPUT` or `OUTPUT` parameters. The procedure listed expects input parameter `@JobName`. Try creating a stored procedure without a parameter or maybe with a default.